# Emacs eshell ls -d doesn't work

Tags: eshell

I would like to list just my folders (not files) with Emacs eshell.

I tried `ls -d .` but it doesn't work. I can achieve this using with bash under term using `ls -d */` but this doesn't work neither under eshell.

I reviewed the eshell ls documentation with `ls help` and I found this:

> List information about the FILEs (the current directory by default).
> Sort entries alphabetically across.
>
> ```
> ...
> -d, --directory      list directory entries instead of contents
> ```
>
> This command is implemented in Lisp.  If an unrecognized option is
> passed to this command, the external version ‘/usr/bin/ls’ will be
> called instead.

but I don't find how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls -d` works in Eshell. As documented, and as in other shells, when asked to list a directory, `ls -d` lists the directory itself and not its contents. It doesn't change what `ls` does when one of its arguments is not a directory.

In Bourne-style shells, and any other program that uses Unix/POSIX-compatible pattern matching, the pattern `*/` only matches subdirectories of the current directory, and not other types of files. (The matches include symbolic links to directories.) Thus `ls -d */` lists the contents of the subdirectories of the current directory. Combined with `-d`, the command `ls -d */` lists the directories themselves, and not the regular files.

In Eshell, `*/` does not restrict matching to directories. Eshell's pattern matching unfortunately does not include this feature. But you can use `*/.` to achieve mostly the same effect, just with an extra trailing `./` in the listing. Thus you can list the subdirectories of the current directory with `ld -d */.` or with `echo */.` since `ls` only does the formatting, not the enumeration of what to list.

Answer (score -1):

When you say that it doesn’t work, what do you mean?

My psychic debugger is telling me that when you run `ls -l .`,  you just see a single line with a `.`, which is confusing you. But that’s what `ls -d` does. `ls foo` shows you the contents of foo if it is a directory, while `ls -d foo` shows you foo itself even if it is a directory. `.` is just a name for the current directory, so `ls -d .` just shows it to you.

`ls -d *` is similar. The `*` is first expanded to the whole contents of the current directory, both files and directories. `ls -d` examines each one and shows them to you, even if they are directories.

What you want is indeed `ls -d */`, which works just fine for me. You don't give any other information, so that’s as far as my guesses will take me.